# How many functions are there from set A of size 5 to set B of size 3 such that $f(A) ⊂ B.$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

i know $n^m$ will be the number of functions but .. i am new with discrete maths.

question is correct..
but what does  $f(A) ⊂ B$ mean is it a trick question  ?

Comment: I don't think it's a trick question.  I think $f(A) \subset B$ is redundant once you're told that you're dealing with functions from $A$ to $B$.  Unless they're using the symbol $\subset$ as opposed to $\subseteq$ to mean that $f(A)$ is a *proper* subset of $B$.

Comment: Normally, $A\subset B$ means : if $x\in A$ then $x\in B$. Some author indeed rather write $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: There are people who think $\subset$ means $\subseteq$ instead of $\subsetneq$. (Do these people also think $<$ means $\leq$?) The existence of such people unfortunately makes the beautiful $\subset$ a symbol to be avoided as it is ambiguous, and instead we have to make do with the horrible $\subsetneq$. (Sorry for being ranty and a bit hyperbolic, but it is one of my biggest notational pet peeves.)

Comment: Older books, in particular, use $A\subset B$ to mean $A\subseteq B.$ But some use the notation to mean $\subsetneq,$ mean8ng $A$ is a *proper* subset of $B.$ It is redundant to say $f(A)\subseteq B,$ so the question might well mean $A\subsetneq B.$

Comment: The answer to this question depends on what your author means by $\subset$. If they mean *proper* subset, than you are looking for functions that don't reach at least one of the elements of $B$. If they do not, it would be a redundant statement on their part, and any function $A\rightarrow B$ would work.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews can i say answer as total number functions excluding onto-functions. if it is true ,then answer this question , this might be helpful for others

Comment: Yeah, nswering the number of onto functions is typically done with inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While often $\subset$ is meant as $\subseteq,$ that here would be a redundant condition, since $f$ being a function from $A$ to $B,$ it is true by definition that $f(A)\subseteq B.$

If the question means $f(A)$ is a *proper* subset of $B,$ then the question is a little harder. The traditional approach is to use inclusion-exclusion in that case.